# Node-cmd: how to change user from root in Node JS

Tags: node.js, bash, cmd, root

If I execute the cmd with node-cmd in Node JS it uses the root user. I need it to be another one, but "su - user" seems not to work. This is the string I use as a bash command:

```
cd /home/leohoy/ && su - leohoy && python3 dataengineering.py
```

Is there a command I can use to switch the user to leohoy?

Comment: `sudo su - leohoy; cd /home/leohoy/ && python3 dataengineering.py`

Comment: CMD doesn't have a Sudo command (it does has RunAs) and CMD uses backslashes to separate path elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As root, you can run:

```
su - leohoy -c "python3 dataengineering.py"
```

With `-c`, the command `python3 dataengineering.py` will run as user leohoy.

Whereas in your example, `python3 dataengineering.py` still runs as root.